# Given the vector field $F(x, y, z) = yi + xj + k$, evaluate $∫_C F•dr$

Tags: calculus

Given the vector field $F(x, y, z) = yi + xj + k$, evaluate $∫_C F•dr$,where C is the boundary of the region enclosed by the triangle with vertices (0,1), (1,0), (0,–1). 
Hi, I have no idea where to begin to solve this question, can someone help me out here? many thanks.

Comment: Um, are you sure? You seem to be working in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ because of $i,j,k$, but your triangle has vertices in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: ya, im sure that is the question, that is why im so confused :(. This question is on my sample final exam with no solution provided and my final is tomorrow